# iTerm2: Select Text keybinding disappeared

Tags: iterm, keybindings

I seem to have inadvertently removed the ability to select text using the keyboard: e.g. <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>←</kbd>.

I've scrolled through the default key bindings in both Preferences > Keys and Preferences > Profiles > Keys. In the latter, Terminal.app Compatibility seems the most natural.

And it's probably really simple...